# Learning constructors and objects

Tags: java, object, constructor

I just had a quiz (luckily no a test) on constructors and objects which went relatively badly.

I thought I had it figured out, but I just don't.

The question we were given was basically to make a sub sandwich simulator. We were just told that it has "bread" "number of vegetables" and "type of meat"

The problem here is genuinely that I do not understand this, and not that I haven't read countlessly about it. So I am reaching out to see if somebody here can actually explain this to me in a way I can understand. It seems like there are just too many methods for what we're trying to do for one.

This is how far I got with it:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
public class SubSandwich{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String bread;
    private int numVegs;
    private String meat;

    // Constructor
    public SubSandwich(String b, int nv, String m){
        bread = b;
        numVegs = nv;
        meat = m;
    }

    // Get the value of bread
    public String getBread(){
        return bread;
    }

    // Get the value of numVegs
    public int getNumVegs(){
        return numVegs;
    }

    // Get the value of meat
    public String getMeat(){
        return meat;
    }

    // Modify the value of bread
    public void setBread(String b){
    }

    // Modify the value of numVegs
    public void setNumVegs(int nv){

    }

    // Modify the value of meat
    public void setMeat(String m){

    }

    // Calculate and return the total cost of a sub sandwich.
    // The total cost is $5.00,
    // plus $0.50 for each vegetable.
    public double getTotalCost(){
        double totalCost = 5.00 + (getNumVegs() * .50);

        return totalCost;
    }

    public String toString(){
        System.out.println("You have a ");
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        SubSandwich sandwich1 = new SubSandwich("White", 2, "Chicken");


    }

    public static void printSandwich(SubSandwich sandwich1){
        System.out.println("The sandwich you ordered is " + sandwich1.getBread() + " and " + sandwich1.getNumVegs() + " vegetables, and " + sandwich1.getMeat() + ".\n That comes to $" + sandwich1.getTotalCost() + "." );
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is what exactly are the 'modify' methods for? How should I use them?

I am sorry if this seems extremely vague, I thought it was, and maybe I just don't understand it enough. This is the template we were given, but I have filled in a few things that I think I understood. I tried asking questions and taking data in the main method, but I can't use non-static methods to return to the main method.

The main thing I am curious about it the modification methods and how exactly I access them are use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is perfectly fine. It sets those private variables at the top of the class.

```
public class SubSandwich{
    private String bread;
    private int numVegs;
    private String meat;

    // Constructor
    public SubSandwich(String b, int nv, String m){
        bread = b;
        numVegs = nv;
        meat = m;
    }
```

Now, you don't understand setters? Try replacing the constructor `bread = b` with `setBread(b)`. In other words, the setter methods are more or less subsets of operations done by the constructor. *It sets values*, nothing complex about that.

Now, this isn't exactly modeling a real world sandwich, but if you want to switch the bread for one particular sandwich

```
SubSandwich blah = new SubSandwich("White", 2, "Chicken");
printSandwich(blah);  // prints white 
blah.setBread("wheat");
printSandwich(blah); // prints wheat
```

You need to implement your methods to reflect that update

You also could implement the toString method, so you can simply do

```
System.out.println(blah);
```

Comment: I think my main problem here is that I still don't understand what the modify methods are used for, I have changed bread = b; meat = m, numVeg = nv; to the corresponding things

Comment: Though setBread() the method is still empty and I don't know how to draw data to it

Comment: You don't have to replace those lines in the constructor. Those methods should be *functional equivalent* to the lines you replaced. One line per method  for example `bread = b;` Done...

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
   public void setBread(String b){
    bread = b;
    }
```

Basically what you're doing is modifying the private variable 'bread' which is being set to whatever 'b' is. When you create a SubSandwich object in your main method you can now decide that 'blah' uses Flat bread instead of White bread.

```
SubSandwich blah = new SubSandwich("White", 2, "Chicken");
blah.setBread("Flat");
```